# service worker: how can read config from an external file (to avoid to commit it?)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My `firebase-messaging-sw.js` starts with

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
```

I then want to load the json configuration object from a file on disk, because we don't want to commit it (not for security, only because every environment has a different config)

I tried

```
var  firebaseConfig = import('src/configs/firebase-config')
```

but I got this error

> import() is disallowed on ServiceWorkerGlobalScope by the HTML specification

How can I obtain to not commit the config and then read json at runtime?

Comment: How about using [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) then?

Comment: The documentation I linked shows that it should work on any path. *"These paths are relative to html document base URL."*

Comment: Yes of course but it doesn't have to be a fully qualified URL. It could start with `./` (relative to the current url) or `/` (relative to the current domain) couldn't it? Otherwise there might be some voodoo going on in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use importScripts :

```
importScripts('serviceWorkerConfig.js');
```

then add your config file to git ignore and it won't be committed

```
.gitigore 
 |- node_modules
 |- serviceWorkerConfig.js
```

Comment: Can you make  a codesandbox ?